# Non-homogeneous PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm following the example on this document:

http://www.math.psu.edu/wysocki/M412/Notes412_10.pdf

If you ctrl + f "Example $19.3$" on page $4$, it's the one that I'm looking at.

Why is the $w(x,t)$ taken to be $x/\pi$ all of a sudden?

Comment: Improve your question please - As I could not improve the question sufficiently without making a question which I give an answer to! A tad circular. In any case that is the derivation so please read the full text.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the definition that the paper uses for Dirichlet boundary conditions:
$$
w(x,t) = a(t) + \frac{x}{L}(b(t)-a(t))\\
a(t) = u(0,t)\;,\;b(t) = u(L,t)
$$
so given your example 9.13 we have
$$

$$
a(t) = u(0,t) = 0\\
b(t) = u(L,t) = u(\pi,t) = 1\implies L = \pi
$$
putting it all together
$$
w(x,t) = 0 + \frac{x}{\pi}(1-0)= \frac{x}{\pi}
$$